# Why was my question downvoted and not closed?

Tags: discussion, questions, downvotes

I asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25156913/why-package-your-java-source-code) question earlier and it was downvoted 5 times in a matter of 10 minutes, I held a short conversation with a user who commented on why I was being downvoted because the question is vague.

So why wasn't it voted to be closed as "Too broad/vague" instead of downvoted to metaphorical oblivion? Correct me if I'm wrong but isn't the point of downvoting to show little effort in researching the question before posting to SO or having a poor-quality question.

My question is concise and explains itself well. I looked at various tutorials on the internet involving packaging and the only advantages ever explained or made obvious in them was that it made your source code better organised.

Should be question have been downvoted or closed, or both?

Comment: I see 4 close votes. It would have gotten closed after one more vote... We require 5 close votes for that to happen.

Comment: As a relatively new user of SO, I get slightly antsy when I see the little reputation I have disappearing.. Especially when it's happening (in my opinion) improperly.

Comment: No idea whether DV and/or CV were proper, as you deleted it. Thus nothing to discuss for any but 10K+. Anyway, one being appropriate does not mean the other is not, though I might refrain from DV if I CV, depending on the question showing promise.

Comment: You asked a bad question that was very close to being closed, and you received some downvotes for it; absolutely nothing improper about that.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist How could I have made the question better? I (personally) don't think that the intent of the question is bad. I haven't been able to find anywhere that clearly explains the advantages and disadvantages of packaging and as someone new to Java who sees packaging often I wonder why.

Comment: I understand the impulse to want to ask "advantage/disadvantage" a.k.a. "A vs. B" questions, but they're too broad for the Stack Exchange format. Some advantages are subjective, and even the objective advantages and differences are too long to list. How far do you want to go? How technical do you want to get with a list in your answer? It's simply too broad. If anything, focus on certain characteristics. *"I understand that packaging does A, B and C. Does this impact X, Y or Z?"* Tell us what you know and what gaps we can fill, don't ask us open-ended questions.

Comment: It just seems that you need to play the "rep game" until you have a certain amount and then you can really tap into the knowledge in SO, seems like a waste for the less experienced users.

I take it my packaging question would've been fine for a SO chat room?

Comment: You don't need to play any "rep game", you just need to ask on-topic questions. And to some extend SO really is not for "less experienced" people. There is, by design, a certain threshold to entry. We cannot teach everyone programming from scratch here, there simply aren't enough resources to go around to do that.

Comment: @deceze It seems that any question regarding the fundamentals of a language are too broad, which is understandable but at the same time, a massive waste. I imagine that there are some 10k+ users who wouldn't mind answering these broad questions but I doubt that the question would survive the onslaught of "I can't get rep from this quickly" would-be answerers. And for new users we can't exactly open a chat to find out these kind of things, and it isn't always easy to find an explicit answer on the internet (like my packaging question).

Comment: I see what you mean, but the solution is still the same: ask an on-topic question. We cannot and will not repeat some explanation which is readily available in a Programming 101 book or the manual. Anything beyond that you may ask. Even simple things are welcome, if they require some explanation beyond what can be found in books. **But**, this question will have to meet the guidelines of SO. Such simple questions must be pretty well formed to demonstrate a need to be answered here, and the possibility to be answerable. Positive recent example: http://stackoverflow.com/q/25157034/476

Comment: Meh, I see it more as you asked a trivial question that could have easily been answered by a little research.  I had no idea what you were talking about (java packages?) so I searched for the term, found this link http://javaworkshop.sourceforge.net/chapter3.html#Introduction and after reading a couple lines I already knew that java packages were what REAL languages call "namespaces" and that they serve to organize code and prevent class name clashes.  Any time you ask trivial questions you risk backlash.  In some tags, more than others.

Comment: I found that packages were used to organise code and mentioned it in my question, the question asked if their were other advantages/disadvantages.. I didn't realise so many devs used packages exclusively for organisation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question had received 4 close votes by the time you deleted it.

Voting to close and up- and down voting are two separate actions; a question can be both off-topic and great, or on-topic and dismal. I'm afraid people felt your question was off-topic and dismal.

Note that even if your question had been closed, voting would not have been disabled. Voting on questions provides other visitors with a signal 'this question is not worth your time', *and* affects your reputation score. Your reputation score reflects how much the community 'trusts' you (privileges are tied to reputation, for example), and you lost some of that trust by posting your question.

We cannot know exactly *why* 5 people down voted; reasons to vote are personal, private. But the tooltip on the down vote button does give a hint as to why people *may* have downvoted: *This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful*. In this instance, your question showed a *lack of research effort*, namely in how Stack Overflow *works*.

When you first joined the site and wanted to ask a question, you were shown the [*How to Ask* page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/advice?), which included a checkbox to tick to acknowledge you'd remember the advice given. That advice included a link to [what is on-topic and acceptable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) as well as what you [should avoid asking about](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Your question was asking for opinions and was too broad, and you could have avoided asking that question had you paid attention to the advice given.

Now that the post has been deleted, your reputation loss has been reverted. Do know however that if you continue to posts off-topic questions and receive downvotes, the system may automatically ban you from asking more questions until you gain community trust in other ways (improve existing questions, create good answers, etc.).

Comment: People felt that the question was off-topic, great, on-topic *and* dismal? :o)

Comment: I do understand that, and I don't really think it works. My first question at SO was very poor and was closed ( [link to question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20334377/how-to-use-and-edit-a-2d-array-in-from-another-class) ), and recently I edited it to a level I find acceptable and hopefully the community does. At the very least it makes it useful for those looking at it, however it's still closed and has received little to no attention (that I can see) since my edit. Am I being to impatient or..?

Comment: @Stormie: your other question indeed is improved somewhat; I edited it some for formatting and removed the 'thanks' (it is extraneous noise), and voted to reopen it. Yes, sometimes such questions are lost, stuck too deep down the rubbish heap to be noticed. Your edit did put it back in the reopen queue but I fear it was voted to be kept closed at the time.

Comment: Well, thanks for clarifying what's heppening with it at the minute at the very least.. There doesn't seem to be much transparency with what happens to questions (the votes to close in from my original question and the vote to reopen my first SO question and it being in the queue for reevaluation etc.. Maybe something to address in the future?

Comment: @Stormie: the *How to Ask* page also links to some more reading material (in the *Related* sidebar); there is some excellent advice there (although Jon's article link is broken at the moment; find it at http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/).

Comment: @Stormie: the help center tells you all you need to know about [closing](http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions) and [reopening](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reopen-questions).

Comment: @MartijnPieters What exactly are users with < 200 rep meant to do to reopen questions aside from pester other users to vote to reopen? Like you said, when a question is buried it go unnoticed.

Comment: @Stormie: Ah, the help page does not mention that the first edit after closing also puts the question into the reopen review queue, automatically. You could bring it up on meta if still not reopened, after a while. In the meantime, feel free to learn about asking good questions and applying the lessons by editing that post.